Unable to Install Dependencies in Angular 15 Project (ngx-admin) Due to Dependency Conflict
I recently cloned an Angular project that uses version 15. However, when I tried to install the dependencies using npm install, I encountered the following error related to dependency resolution:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: ngx-admin@11.0.0
npm error Found: @angular/common@15.2.10
npm error node_modules/@angular/common
npm error   @angular/common@"^15.2.10" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/google-maps@12.2.13
npm error node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm error   @angular/google-maps@"^12.2.13" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\ANAS\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-04T20_28_26_776Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ANAS\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-04T20_28_26_776Z-debug-0.log

please share the package.json

For the quick and easy, but not-so-stable solution, you can juste run
npm i -f

Otherwise, it means your dependencies have dependencies, that are at the wrong version in this particular project. To resolve that, you have to either resolve all conflicts by hand, or I you know what you're doing, override them one by one.

--force and --legacy-peer-deps do not work in this case.

And why is that ?
